# StumbleUpon bookmarklet to favorite any website (not the ones I get to using their toolbar)

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarklet, stumbleupon

### The situation

I'm looking for an easy way to thumbs-up/favorite any websites which I've found browsing the web (not using StumbleUpon). I want it among my other StumbleUpon favourites (to customize my future stumbles).

### Current possibilities we have

- [Grab this browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kcahibnffhnnjcedflmchmokndkjnhpg) (for Chrome)

  - Advantage: can be used to load up the SU toolbar on any page thus allowing me to fav.
  - Disadvantage: Unnecessarily overhead: it loads itself to Every single tab I open from the point I enable the toolbar. Slows down every page load and takes up precious memory (haven't profiled it though). Cumbersome to enable and disable it every time.
- [Use this url as a bookmark](http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit) (I use this option currently)

  - Advantage: Isn't a resource hog in any way, very lightweight for what it does.
  - Disadvantage: Have to go through a number of steps *(Copy current url, open new tab, click bookmark, click in textbox, CTRL+A to select all, paste, click submit, click 'I like it', close tab)* **That is as much as 9 steps!** Which are the same for every site I need to use it with, and those steps could be easily automated.

### Solution I'm looking for

A simple and clean JS bookmarklet, which is capable of the following:

- Can be clicked on any site.
- Does it's job in the background (doesn't distract on top of what is pointed out next)
- Notifies whether my action worked (the url is submitted and is now among my other favorites)
- Notifies of failure either due to network problem, or that the user is not logged in, etc...
- If the url is yet to be added to SU's database, open a new tab and take me to the appropriate page so that I can add it myself.

It is not a big problem if there are bookmarklets which do only a subset of what I outlined as I think I would be able to modify it more tailored to my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, this is the closest I could get so far with the bookmarklet:

```
javascript:document.location.href='http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url='+document.URL+'&title='+document.title.replace(/ /g,'+');
```

([origin](http://www.firefoxfacts.com/2007/09/21/use-stumbleupon-without-the-toolbar/))

Even though it's not fully satisfying, it does the core job.

I'm still looking for more a delicate way for going about this. I'll consider expanding, improving this bookmarklet, and I am of course still open to your suggestions, improvements. Tell me about them and I think I'll be able to add them here.

Comment: Works like a charm :)

Comment: This is a great bookmarklet I have been looking for to submit content to StumbleUpon. Thanks!